# Preprogrammed Atmel microcontrollers?

Tags: microcontroller, programming, programmer, atmel, production

Where can you buy preprogrammed atmel microcontrollers such as the attiny13a microcontroller in a surface mount package?

I know you can buy preprogrammed PIC microcontrollers, but not atmel microcontrollers...

Comment: What quantities?

Comment: "preprogrammed" with what, exactly?

Comment: Digikey's [product page for Attiny13A](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/ATTINY13A-SSU/ATTINY13A-SSU-ND/1914672) says the following: "This part can be programmed by Digi-Key; for details please..."

Comment: You may also want to consider doing the programming as part of a spring-pin fixture which could also do some basic testing of the installation and potential other components.

Comment: This will be a "small" production run of 10 panels of 100 boards each (so 1000 boards). Following this production run, I may need 5000 boards programmed...

Answer (score 2):

You tagged the question [production](/questions/tagged/production), does that imply large quantities, at least hundreds to thousands per year? If you're a professional you may buy through distribution, and most distris have a programming service for all microcontrollers on their line card.

You have options like a unique code programmed where you want it, and labeling like kapton or lasering. It will cost roughly between 10 and 15 cents, depending on quantities.

I've used programming services from EBV and Spoerle. PCB assembly shops may also offer the service, but I guess they have it done by the distri as well, so you may better go directly there.

Comment: Of two local shops I've used, one uses the distributor, and one programs in-house, but isn't instrumented to do every uprocessor.  Both options worked out to be very similar in price.  If you're using an assembler, I suppose the approach to decide who's doing the programming would depend upon whether you want to do things turnkey or use a partially or fully kitted approach.

Comment: Does such programming services support programming unique data per device, i.e. device_id and secret_key ?